# Magento 2 - main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento2, varnish

Good evening everyone

I manage a Magento 2.2.3 Store, recently store is crashing a lot.  Sometimes keeps looping on frontend for about a minute, sometimes happens on backend and sometimes gateway timeout error shows up. Store is on production mode, cache options enabled, Varnish as default cache manager. Store got better performance with those changes but system.log file in var/log/ keeps growing constantly showing following errors againa and again...

```html
[2021-10-13 18:22:50] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 18:35:32] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 18:47:45] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Item Magento_Backend::system_currency was removed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id emizentech::base was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Lof_All::lof_all was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Lof_All::license was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Lof_All::license_manage was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Lof_All::market_manage was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::magecompcityandregionmanager was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::states was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::cities was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::zip was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magecomp_Cityandregionmanager::cityandregionmanager_configuration was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design_schedule was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_store was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::dashboard was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_tools was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_design was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_convert was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_cache was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_communications was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_seo was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::marketing_user_content was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::content_elements was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::stores_attributes was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::other_settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::system_other_settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backend::setup_wizard was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Config::system_config was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Theme::design_config was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Theme::system_design_theme was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Backup::system_tools_backup was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_manage was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_online was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Customer::customer_group was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_AdminNotification::system_adminnotification was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Indexer::system_index was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_page was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Cms::cms_block was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_products was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_categories was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_attributes was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::catalog_attributes_sets was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Catalog::inventory was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::search_terms was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::search_synonyms was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Widget::cms_widget_instance was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_users was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_roles was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_User::system_acl_locks was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CatalogRule::promo_catalog was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_template was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_queue was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_subscriber was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Newsletter::newsletter_problem was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_rates was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency_symbols was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_extensions was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Integration::system_integrations was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_operation was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_order was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_invoice was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_shipment was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_creditmemo was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::sales_transactions was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sales::system_order_statuses was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Downloadable::report_products_downloads was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_import was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_export was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_ImportExport::system_convert_history was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Email::template was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_EncryptionKey::system_crypt_key was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::advanced_reporting was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Analytics::bi_essentials was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Marketplace::partners was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_marketing was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_sales was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_tax was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_invoiced was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_shipping was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_refunded was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_salesroot_coupons was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_product was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_shopcart_abandoned was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_bestsellers was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_sold was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_viewed was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_products_lowstock was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_accounts was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_totals was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_customers_orders was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Reports::report_statistics_refresh was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Search::report_search_term was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_SalesRule::promo_quote was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::report_salesroot_paypal_settlement_reports was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Paypal::paypal_billing_agreement was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_CheckoutAgreements::sales_checkoutagreement was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_ratings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::catalog_reviews_ratings_reviews_all was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_customer was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Review::report_review_product was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_UrlRewrite::urlrewrite was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Sitemap::catalog_sitemap was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rules was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Tax::sales_tax_rates was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_TaxImportExport::system_convert_tax was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Variable::system_variable was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Magento_Braintree::settlement_report was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Bannerslider::bannerslider_bannerslider was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Bannerslider::bannerslider_banners was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Bannerslider::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Brandslider::brandslider_brandslider was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Brandslider::brandslider_brands was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Brandslider::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Hozmegamenu::hozmegamenu was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Hozmegamenu::hozmegamenu_hozmegamenu was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Hozmegamenu::items was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Randomproductslider::randomproductslider was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Randomproductslider::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Template::template was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Template::items was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Testimonial::testimonial_testimonial was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Testimonial::testimonial_testimos was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Testimonial::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Themeoptions::themeoptions was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Plazathemes_Themeoptions::settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id SendGrid_EmailDeliverySimplified::SendGridAdmin was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id SendGrid_EmailDeliverySimplified::Settings was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id SendGrid_EmailDeliverySimplified::Statistics was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::shipping was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::carriers was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::locations was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::packaging was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:51:13] main.INFO: Add of item with id Temando_Shipping::dispatches was processed [] []
[2021-10-13 18:52:21] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 19:00:58] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 19:09:28] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 19:27:06] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 19:40:49] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 19:45:46] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:08:13] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:44:19] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:49:54] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:53:03] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:59:42] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 20:59:59] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 21:00:12] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
[2021-10-13 21:06:07] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []
```

I apprecciate the kind human soul that could help me solving this issue. I've been in this for a long time!

Comment: Please provide some clues of what Magento code is being used.

Comment: thanks for help. Im not using any code. Error log it's getting bigger and bigger with this pattern. line main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] [] repeats a lot and then errors start to come out. recently im getting error 
main.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 100000
How can i identify where is error source? Hope you can help

Comment: If you can catch it when it happens, run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` from another connection before it stops.  That might get the naughty query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Capture shows two results on database http://prntscr.com/1xbnt16

Comment: Were you logged in as the same "user" when you took that image?  I should have pointed out that you need to be logged in as mysql's "root" so you can see all the processes.

Comment: Actually, you did, my bad. is there any other way to see a more complete  detail of magento logs? I dont have root access to show full processlist.